# run time error 91 : Object Variable or With block variable not set in excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have a macro :

```
Sheets("AMEND ESTIMATE").Select

Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("AMEND QUOTE").Range("G4").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(41, 3).Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("AMEND QUOTE").Select

Range("G4").Offset(14, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


'#2


Sheets("AMEND ESTIMATE").Select

Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("AMEND QUOTE").Range("H4").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(41, 3).Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("AMEND QUOTE").Select

Range("H4").Offset(14, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


'#3


Sheets("AMEND ESTIMATE").Select

Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("AMEND QUOTE").Range("I4").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(41, 3).Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("AMEND QUOTE").Select

Range("I4").Offset(14, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

As you have seen, this macro finds a range from Amend Quote inside AMEND ESTIMATE(worksheets), gets a value and pastes in a certain offset cell in Amend Quote.

This was working fine, but now it is throwing run time error 91.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Hi, i forgot to mention that this repeats 50 times. Can you please help.

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your find isn't finding anything. You need to put a bit of error handling to account for when the find returns no result, by setting the result of the find action to a variable and then doing the activate on the variable only if there's something there.

Something like this:

EDIT - updated code below including behaviour to allow the sub to exit if the search term isn't found or if the search term is a zero length string.

I've also tidied up your code a lot to remove 'select then manipulate' - you can manipulate the cells without selecting them first, it'll save a lot of processing time.

Finally I've condensed the whole 50 iterations into a single loop rather than repeating the same action 50 times changing the cell reference by 1 column each time.

Please remember to accept my answer as correct if it helps you.

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim aEst As Worksheet, aQuo As Worksheet

'Set your sheet names into variables for easier referencing
Set aEst = Sheets("AMEND ESTIMATE")
Set aQuo = Sheets("AMEND QUOTE")

For i = 7 To 57 '7 = Column H, 8 = Column G, etc.

    'Set the address of the found value to the rng variable
    Set rng = aEst.Cells.Find(What:=aQuo.Cells(4, i).Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'CHECK IF THE SEARCH TERM (FROM QUOTE SHEET) WAS FOUND IN THE TARGET SHEET (ESTIMATE)

        If Not rng = "" Then 'CHECK IF THE SEARCH TERM WAS A ZERO LENGTH STRING

            rng.Offset(41, 3).Copy 'Copy the cell 41 rows down and 3 columns across
            aQuo.Cells(4, i).Offset(14, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Paste into the cell 14 rows below the original search term in the QUOTE sheet

        ElseIf rng = "" Then 'EXIT SUB IF SEARCH TERM WAS A ZERO LENGTH STRING
            MsgBox "Work is Done"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then 'EXIT SUB IF SEARCH TERM WAS NOT FOUND IN THE TARGET SHEET
        MsgBox "Work is Done"
        Exit Sub

    End If

Next i 'Move to the next column across and loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Harley,  you said " The issue is that your find isn't finding anything" - but  i am trying to find "Sheets("AMEND QUOTE").Range("G4").Value" from another sheet. I saw there is a value there and it is definitely not empty. I am very greatful for the code you provided , i will use and see if it works for me. what i want to know is that , it worked 2 days back and it wont work now , same code , everyline ,,, WHY ???? what is run time error 91 and how can i get around it, could you please let me know. i am using excel 2013, not a vb geek. Pls help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Harley , you are right ? it is not finding anything from another page. Now how do i get the macro to find a cell value from another sheet here in this sheet. it needs to repeat the find function 50 times with out breaking or showing error 91. Pls help if you can... thanks a lot

Comment: So you're searching in Sheet AMEND ESTIMATE for the value in cell G4 of AMEND QUOTE, but that value isn't found. So if the value of G4 in AMEND QUOTE is 'Example', you should find that no cell on AMEND ESTIMATE matches the string 'Example'. I'll put an edit in my answer which allows the sub to continue when the value isn't found. Please remember to mark my answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: Harley, Thank you mate. You are a genuis. Where do i put down that this answer is correct. Pls help me.

Comment: Hey Harley, it is doing the work fine, can you please tell me how do i come out of the loop. say if the value is empty come out of loop and exit sub with msg saying the work is done. Pls help

Comment: because now , i dont have value in Amend Quote cell "i4", still the macro is running and placing a empty value, how do i break the loop if no value is found. Pls help

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow for exit sub if the search term isn't found in the target sheet (`elseif rng = nothing then`) or if the search term is a zero length string i.e. no value in the search cell from Amend Quote (`elseif rng = "" then`), depending on what you want to do, one or both of these should work for you. Step through the code with F8 to watch it happening and figure out which applies. To the left of my answer is an up arrow (upvote) and you should see a tick to accept the answer as correct. Please consider using both if you found my answer extra helpful.

Comment: Hi there. It doesn't look like your vote and acceptance has quite taken, could you try once more for me? It's the little up/down arrow with a 0 in between right below where it says '1 Answer' and right to the left of where my answer starts. Below that is a little tick mark which should turn green after you click it.

Comment: HI Harley, it turned into green now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Harley, I have another small issue.

Comment: Hi Harley, I have another small issue. earlier you have given a piece of code which says "rng.Offset(41, 3).Copy", what i want now is that find a rng(cell) and go down 2 rows 0 Columns, selection starts there until 14 rows , 0 columns and pasted in Quote Master sheet. Con you pls help me with the code

Comment: Hi Vivek. This should really be a new question, but in brief - the offset method takes 2 parameters within the brackets. The first number is the rows to count down, the second is the columns to count across. So to go down 2 rows and across 0 columns would be offset(2,0)

Comment: 'Declare FSO
    Dim FSO
    
    'Create Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    '-----

    'Declare Destination Folder Path
    Dim DFolderP As String
    
    'Change to match the destination folder path
    DFolderP = Sheets("CONSOLE").Range("G6").Value

Comment: 'Declare FSO
    Dim FSO
    
    'Create Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    '-----

    'Declare Destination Folder Path
    Dim DFolderP As String
    
    'Change to match the destination folder path
    DFolderP = Sheets("CONSOLE").Range("G6").Value
    
    '-----
    
    'Load Picture button
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename

Comment: HI Harley , can you pls help with this code pls, what i want ot do next is , simply .................... once i open a picture from the getopenfilename browser window, that file should be (only picture file) copied in to my  console sheet cell C6. Could you pls help

Comment: Finally...........i came upto this ..........................Dim p As Picture
    Dim sPath As String, sFileName As String, s As String
    
    sPath = "C:\Users\Vivek\Downloads\SMCS\"
    
    'Open browser to select a picture
    Thisfile = Application.GetOpenFilename

    
    sFileName = Thisfile
    s = sPath & sFileName
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert (s)....................... and i am getting this error....................1004 Insert method of pictures class failed

Comment: Hi vivek. Please post as a new question and myself or one of the other community members will help quickly I'm sure.